# Get Range From A Separate Sheet Using a Variable in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to get a range from another sheet based upon the Column Letter which is obtained from the current sheet.

So say that I designate A2 on the current sheet to the letter G.

I would then ask A10 to =AVERAGE('Sheet1'!(A2)2:(A2)999)

So essentially it would be =AVERAGE('Sheet1'!G2:G999)

However, this doesn't work. Anyone have any idea how to make this worK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the Indirect() function:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!" & A2 & "2:" & A2 & "999"))
```

Comment: @Sparatan117 Glad to help.  Please come back in a few minutes and mark as correct.